# Prop in template not showing with VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I've been trying to pass a prop in a component's template.
I think I'm missing some points here, and I didn't start to include my components in single files yet.

**app.js**

```
Vue.component('chat-response', {
    props: ['response', 'senderClass'],
    template: '<div>From {{ senderClass }} : {{ response.text }}</div>'
})

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app_chat',
    data: {
        responseList: [
            { id: 0, text: 'Response 1', type: 'Owner' },
            { id: 1, text: 'Response 2', type: 'Other' },
            { id: 2, text: 'Response 3', type: 'None' }
        ]
    }
})
```

**page.html**

```
...
<chat-response v-for="response in responseList"
                                   v-bind:key="response.id"
                                   v-bind:response="response"
                                   v-bind:senderClass="response.type"></chat-response>
...
```

**Output** :

```
From : Response 1
From : Response 2
From : Response 3
```

As we see, senderClass won't show up. I've tried different methods and only got errors that I could understand after reading around.

I don't wish to use **response.type** instead of **senderClass** because in the meantime, I'm setting **senderClass** after **mounted** with a real css class.

Maybe it's my approach that's completely wrong, could you give me some hints ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the name of your property is wrong. Just change in **page.html** `v-bind:senderClass="response.type"` to `v-bind:sender-class="response.type"`

http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/310360/

HTML attribute names are case-insensitive. Any uppercase character will be interpreted as lowercase. So camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-cased equivalents.

Comment: You are perfectly right and it works now, I feel stupid now, I'm so used to camelCased ! Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what Jns said You could get rid of v-bind altogether and just use :`varibaleName` for bindings.

Link to fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/654614/#&togetherjs=J9vgbNaR7m

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I understand, I could use v-bind:class= and :class= , both will do the same but it's shorter.

Comment: Yeah, I meant just that :-)